# How to change Joomla component's view default format?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have a custom Joomla 3.4.1 component which has a view that displays data either in JSON format (from views/myview/view.json.php file) or HTML (from views/myview/view.html.php file) format. Is there a way how to change the default view's format from HTML to JSON so that

```
http://example.com/component/mycomponent/myview
```

returns JSON data instead of HTML while:

```
http://example.com/component/mycomponent/myview?format=html
```

still returns the HTML template of the view?

EDIT:

As far as I get is this router:

```
function TouristGuideParseRoute($segments) {
  $count = count($segments);
  $parameters = array();
  if ($count > 0) {
    $parameters['view'] = $segments[0];
  }
  if ($count > 1) {
    $parameters['task'] = $segments[1];
  }
  if ($count > 2) {
    $parameters['id'] = $segments[2];
  }
  if ($count > 3) {
    $parameters['format'] = $segments[3];
  }

  if (($parameters['view'] == 'api') && empty($parameters['format'])) {
    $application = JFactory::getApplication();
    $input = $application->input;
    $parameters['format'] = $input->getString('format', 'json');
  }
  return $parameters;
}
```

which displays JSON format even if URL contains `?format=html` because in this router the `$application->input` is empty (probably populated later on in Joomla request processing chain) and thus `$input->getString('format','json')` returns `json` all the time.

Comment: you can directly echo your json data to php file of views templates.

Comment: I know but that does not solve the problem, that when the default format is HTML, the Joomla page frame (in HTML) is automatically attached to the response. Furthermore, since the HTML format is default how can I check that the view was requested without the format specified? There is 'html' in JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('format').

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, set your default format manually like this (Joomla 3)

```
$input = JFactory::getDocument()->input;
$format = $input->get('format','json','STR');
$view = $this->getView($view_name, $format);
$view->display($tpl);
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Almost! Althought this seems to work in a sense that the correct view file is used to render the template but the Joomla still adds the page HTML content around the response. I tried to google "joomla force raw output" but nothing like suggestions in http://w3facility.org/question/joomla-force-raw-output/ worked to force the raw JSON output.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom component has a router (as I would assume from your example urls) that is where you'd set the default to be JSON.

In the PARSE function you'll want to set...

`$vars['format'] = 'json';`

Take a look at this semi-current tutorial on [Joomla Docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component#A_More_Advanced_Example).
Then/Or do something like...

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$outputFormat = $jinput->getString('format', 'json');
$vars['format'] = ($outputFormat == 'json') ? 'json' : 'html';`
```

Note that I'm using an intermediate variable and checking it against the default (line 2) so that it is constrained to two specific options (a user cant type `?format=blahblah` and have the router get messed up with `$vars['format'] = 'blahblah'`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunatelly this forces JSON format without possibility to set it back to HTML. See the question edit for details.

Comment: This forces the default to be JSON, but you can override that by adding `?format=html` to the url (1st line gets the input object, 2nd line gets the `format` request variable setting to json if not present, 3rd line is a safety ensuring only values of json or html are applied in the router).

Comment: I'm sorry but as I already wrote overriding format with `?format=html` does not work in this case because `JFactory::getApplication()->input` is empty in the router function for some reason even if URL contains that parameter.